# Is manipulating the "read-offset" as kafka consumer bad-practice?

Tags: apache-kafka, publish-subscribe, software-design

We have an ongoing discussion about the correct (or intended) usage of Kafka for events.

The arguing point is the ability of a consumer to not only subscribe (or resubscribe) to a topic but also to modify its own read offset.

Am I right in saying that **"A consumer should be design in a way that it never modifies its own read offset!"**

Reasoning behind this:

- The consumer cannot know what events actually are stored inside a topic (log retention)
- ... So restoring a complete state from "delta"-events is not possible.
- The consumer has consumed an event once and confirmed this to the broker. why consuming again?

Comment: A consumer should be able to rewind itself, if needed. But the other option is to create a new consumer group

Comment: Also, there are different types of consumers. In Kafka Streams API, for example, if you maintain a `changelog` compacted topic, then you would always want to re-consume the entire topic from the beginning, if the consumer re-schedules on another machine for example, to get the complete view. Think a bank balance of plus and minuses, starting from zero.

Answer (score 0):

If your consumer instances belongs to same consumer group, consumer need not to keep the state of reading from topic.  The state of reading is nothing but offset of topic up to which record your consumer read so far. If your topic has multiple partitions consumers belong to the same consumer group can distribute the work load among consumers. In case one of the consumers crashed or failed other consumers from same consumer group will be aware of from which partition offset they continue to consume the record.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the question is asking for. Rather - should the consumer be able to do `commitSync(readOffsets - X)`?